# Append element in JSON and don't overwritting

Tags: javascript, json

I'm writting a JSON and adding into a file

But my problem is that append the same value and overwirtting

When I execute the script, i need to add the new value into the file and not overwritting

I'm tring to read the existing JSON array from the file, append to it in Javascript, then write the entire thing back to a file

Need help, thanks

```
var obj = {
 table: []
};

obj.table.push({"executionDate":date,
    "issueID":key,
    "priority":{
    "jira": priority, 
    "computed":score1
    },
    "expectedValue":{
        "jira": expected, 
        "computed":score2
    }
})

var json = JSON.stringify(obj);


fs.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', json, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) console.error(err)
    });

fs.readFile('myjsonfile.json', 'utf8', function readFileCallback(err, data){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
    obj = JSON.parse(data); //now it an object
    obj.table.push({"executionDate":date,
    "issueID":key,
    "priority":{
        "jira": priority, 
        "computed":score1
    },
    "expectedValue":{
        "jira": expected, 
        "computed":score2
        }

    }); //add some data
    json = JSON.stringify(obj); //convert it back to json
    fs.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', json, 'utf8', function (err) {
        if (err) console.error(err)
    }); // write it back 
}});
```

Actual result :

```
[{
    "executionDate": 25 / 03 / 2019,
    "issueID": 1,
    "priority": {
        "jira": important,
        "computed": 10
    },
    "expectedValue": {
        "jira": expected,
        "computed": 20
    }
},
{
    "executionDate": 25 / 03 / 2019,
    "issueID": 1,
    "priority": {
        "jira": important,
        "computed": 10
    },
    "expectedValue": {
        "jira": expected,
        "computed": 20
    }
}]
```

Expected result:

```
[{
    "executionDate": 25 / 03 / 2019,
    "issueID": 1,
    "priority": {
        "jira": important,
        "computed": 10
    },
    "expectedValue": {
        "jira": expected,
        "computed": 20
    }
},
{
    "executionDate": 26 / 03 / 2019,
    "issueID": 2,
    "priority": {
        "jira": important,
        "computed": 20
    },
    "expectedValue": {
        "jira": expected,
        "computed": 30
    }
}]
```

Comment: It looks like you're using same value populated in variables such as score1, score2 and data and making it as json and writing in the second time. This is the reason why you're seeing same data twice.

Comment: Ok but the problem is that the variable score1 score 2 can change.

Comment: if changes then it will be reflected in the file. I believe your problem right now is that your array in json file has same data in both indexes. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes you are right, I need to use this form of JSON

Comment: ok then the data present in the indexes will change only if the data stored in the variable changed. Since I see that you're using same data and making object, you have this issue

Comment: To put it simply, I have 4 variables. I have to structure them through a JSON.
Whenever I execute the script, the JSON is added to a file even if the values ​​do not change. If I execute 5 times then I must have 5 JSON into the same file